# Specify colors in a Gadfly (Julia) boxplot

Tags: colors, julia, seaborn, boxplot, gadfly

I am trying to reproduce [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_boxplot.html) Seaborn plot using Gadfly.

The code I have so far is:

```
using CSV, DataFrames, Gadfly

download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv", "tips.csv")
tips = DataFrame(CSV.File("tips.csv"));

plot(
    tips, 
    x = :day, 
    y = :total_bill, 
    color = :smoker, 
    Geom.boxplot, 
    Scale.x_discrete(levels = ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]), 
    Theme(
        key_position = :top, 
        boxplot_spacing = 20px
        ), 
    )
```

I would like to specify the colors "green" and "purple" to match the Seaborn plot.
Any suggestions how to do this in Gadfly?

Additional:

- How to set the `smoker` order from `yes` to `no`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a line with `Scale.color_discrete_manual`:

```
using CSV, DataFrames, Gadfly

download(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv",
    "tips.csv",
)
tips = DataFrame(CSV.File("tips.csv"));

plot(
    tips,
    x = :day,
    y = :total_bill,
    color = :smoker,
    Geom.boxplot,
    Scale.x_discrete(levels = ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]),
    Scale.color_discrete_manual("purple", "green", order=[2, 1]),
    Theme(key_position = :top, boxplot_spacing = 20px),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how do I the order for `smoking` to Yes/No (instead of No/Yes)?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the order in the Scale specification.